# A question from Richard Hamilton's paper "A matrix Harnack estimate for the heat equation"

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, linear-algebra, matrices, heat-equation, tensor

Richard Hamilton "A matrix Harnack estimate for the heat equation. Communications in Analysis and Geometry. 1(1993), 113-126."
On page 125, at the end of the proof of Theorem 4.3, I abstract the question and can be described as (Einstein's summation convention):

> Let $P$ be a $(0,4)$-tensor. $P_{ikjl}$ is skew-symmetric in $i$ and $k$, skew-symmetric in $j$ and $l$, symmetric in $\{ik\}$ and $\{jl\}$. For any vectors $v$ and $w$, $P_{ikjl}v_iw_kv_jw_l\ge 0$. Let $(N_{ij})$ be a real symmetric matrix. Prove that **if $v$  is a vector satisfying $N_{ij}v_j=0$, then $P_{ikjl}N_{kl}v_iv_j\ge 0$**.

**How to prove this proposition?**

Professor Hamilton says that "it is clear if we diagonalize $N_{kl}$ with respect to a basis". However, I have not thought clearly about this, and the following example seems to negate this proposition.

> Suppose that the basic vector space is $2$-dimensional.
> $N=\begin{bmatrix}
> -1 & 0\\
> 0 & 0
> \end{bmatrix}$, $v=\begin{bmatrix}
> 0\\
> 1
> \end{bmatrix}$, then $P_{ikjl}N_{kl}v_iv_j=-P_{2121}\le 0$.

Comment: A few lines before, Hamilton shows that the matrix $N_{ij}$ is semipositive definite!

Comment: Thank you for your comments, however, it seems to me that $N_{ij}\ge 0$ is the goal, and we have to prove that $P_{ikjl}N_{kl}\ge 0$ to use the maximum principle for matrices and get $N_{ij}\ge 0$.
@YangMills

Comment: That's how the tensor maximum principle works: you check that $N_{ij}\geq 0$ at time $t=0$, and then you check that at the first positive time where $N$ is still semipositive definite and has a nontrivial kernel, the evolution operator is nonnegative when applied to a vector in the kernel. So, in the computation that you are looking at, we do have that $N_{ij}\geq 0$

Comment: I know how to use the tensor maximum principle. However, my problem is how to make sure that we can find a first positive time that satisfies "at the first positive time where $N$ is still semipositive definite and has a nontrivial kernel".    
Is it possible to perturb $N$ slightly to get $\tilde N$, and then show that $\tilde N$ is positive definite on an initial closed interval? @YangMills

Comment: This is very standard, please see e.g. the book by Chow-Knopf "The Ricci flow: an introduction", Theorem 4.6 p.97. In short, you can perturb $N$ slightly by adding a small, time-dependent multiple of the evolving metric $g(t)$

Comment: Ok, I have figured it out with your help. Thanks for your reply. Best wishes! @YangMills